# YouTube OAuth does not work in server, work with localhost

Tags: java, youtube

I am implement OAuth 2 for youTube api..

```
public class LocalServerReceiverRetriever {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

    private static LocalServerReceiver localServerReceiver = null;

    public static LocalServerReceiver getLocalServerReceiver(){
        if(localServerReceiver == null){
            localServerReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8081).build();
        }else{
            try {
                localServerReceiver.stop();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage() + e.getCause());
            }
            localServerReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8081).build();
        }
        return localServerReceiver ;
    }
}
```

public static Credential authorize(List scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException {

```
    // Load client secrets.
   // more code....

    // Build the local server and bind it to port 8081
    LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = LocalServerReceiverRetriever.getLocalServerReceiver();

    logger.debug("localReceiver set up to 8081");

    // Authorize.
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
```

}

It is **working in local**. Logically I change the callback URL to http://localhost:8081/CallBack.. Working fine in local but when I deploy to **AWS server with public IP, it does not work.**.

Showing address already in use for 8081 exception and even not redirect to google auth page.

Answer (score 0):

That simply means port 8081 has been occupied by some other service on AWS . Either stop that service , or choose a new port other than 8081 for your application. It will work.

Comment: Before OAuth, 8081 is not in use. Only after I call OAuth, it is used and has same process id as Java.

Comment: Same process id as Java ? Anyways why don't you try some other port ? Is it happening with whatever port you choose?